# Going from a for loop to arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
for i in range(2,Nx-2):
    lyr1[i]=lyr0[i]-coef*(lyr0[i]*(lyr0[i+1]-lyr0[i-1])/2+(dsqr/(deltax)**2)*(lyr0[i+2]-2*lyr0[i+1]+2*lyr0[i-1]-lyr0[i-2]))

lyr1=lyr0[0:Nx]-coef*(lyr0[0:Nx]*(lyr0[2:Nx]-lyr0[0:Nx-2])/2+(dsqr/(deltax)**2)*(lyr0[1:Nx+1]-2*lyr0[0:Nx]+2*lyr0[2:Nx-2]-lyr0[3:Nx-3]))
```

I'm trying to change my for loop (above) into an operation on arrays. I am currently getting a broadcast error, but I need to be able to only select portions of the array to match my numerical integration scheme. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What in tarnation is this code doing.

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: This is a snippet of a longer code, but it's for numerical integration. I have layers (which are layers of discrete time) in the y direction and the x direction is spatial on each time layer. I need to take points on the x scale and add/subtract/divide/multiply them to make up the next layer in time.

Comment: Yes, I am using numpy. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Divide it into pieces that we can understand at a glance.  I also see repeated use of indexing like `lyr0[0:Nx]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use vectors of different dimensions (due to your slicing), e.g., `len(lyr0[0:Nx]) == 2 + len(lyr0[2:Nx])`. Numpy tries to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) these operations to match the vector sizes, but they have incompatible dimensions (not being 1, not being multiples of each other etc.).

However, broadcasting is not what you want to do in the first place (judging from your loop implementation). It seems you rather want to do a look-ahead / look-back. Try shifting the values in `lyr0` explicitly by using numpy's [roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function instead.